# How do i call the Google-Cloud-Messaging API in my android client code from Qt?

Tags: java, android, google-play-services

I have followed these docs:
https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gs.html

Downloading and referencing the Google Play Services API through the command line tools provided from android. I have created the `AndroidManifest.xml` and now I am ready to create an Android GCM client.

The problem is: I am using Qt and all these libraries are Java.

How do I call the API in my code? Do i need to #include or import something from my code in order to call the Java functions?

Comment: ...Huh. One of the few instances where both [tag:java] and [tag:c++] are both arguably applicable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow this tutorial
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/
or this one 
http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-send-push-notifications-using-gcm-service/

Comment: Thanks, i will check it out shortly!

Comment: Very nice tutorials but they also use Java on the client side. So it still does not answer my question which is: How do I call these Java functions from Qt/c++.

Comment: see this
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/22881/How-to-Call-Java-Functions-from-C-Using-JNI

Comment: Thank you sir! This will help me out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qandroidjniobject.html

the module "QT += androidextras" allows Qt to integrate Java in the application.